# Images have gap between them

Tags: css, sharepoint

I have a some images that I need to line up without any gaps. I can get them fine in jsFiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/QZLSf/2/

But on the actual SharePoint site the images have a gap between them, kind of like http://jsfiddle.net/QZLSf/1/

I have checked with FireBug and the images, and links, have all the properties they should have, but I can't get rid of that gap.

What could I be missing?

EDIT: I know that the second link has footerlinks defined as a class, but I was just using that to illustrate the problem I'm having. That's not what my actual code is.

EDIT: EDIT: Ok guys there seems to be a misunderstanding as to what I am asking here. I know *HOW* to get the required result, just that it isn't working on the SharePoint site. I just need advice on what might be wrong as everything that should work isn't working.

Comment: The second jsfiddle has "footerlinks" defined as a class instead of an ID so the CSS isn't doing anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's just the way it is. You have to set the margin-left to -4px

```
.footerlinks img {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
.footerlinks img:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QZLSf/11/

EDIT: This solution is more correct. I fixed the margin on the first child.

Comment: That's not just the way it is. I could fudge it with moving the images but that is not a solution to my problem. As I have shown, it works when on it's own, but isn't working on the SharePoint site.

Comment: HTML and CSS are rendered in the browser. Unless SharePoint is overriding your CSS somewhere there should be no difference in how identical HTML and CSS are displayed (in the same browser).

Comment: While I am very hesitant to fudge styles like this it is the only solution that is working. I am sure there is another underlying issue that I can't put my finger on yet, but I'll give you credit for the answer, grudgingly.

Comment: Negative margins are valid CSS according to W3C so don't feel like by using them you are fudging your code. In most cases they are not needed but in this common situation they do their job.

Answer (score 2):

### Remove the whitespace/line breaks between images.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QZLSf/12/

Comment: Whitespace does not make a difference. Whitespace does not get displayed. If you check http://jsfiddle.net/QZLSf/3/ you will see that it works anyway, if you also check http://jsfiddle.net/QZLSf/7/ you will see that even with masses of whitespace and line breaks it still works.

Comment: @anothershrubery whitespace does get displayed if there's a line break in the HTML.. and the images are still inline elements (inyour second example above they're blocks hence no space in them) It is the browser implementation for inline elements and is just the way it is, that whitespace however is `word-spacing` and rather than hack the HTML or fudge margins, perhaps best to work with the actual property?

Comment: It's crazy, when you are not that experienced with CSS, you check out the images in developer tools and you see no margins and no paddings, borders, what so ever, fu..ing white-space :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just posted this solution elsewhere and think it's the same thing.. is your Sharepoint implementation putting the `<img>` elements on separate lines in the HTML?

In your fiddle you have them all on one line.. if that's the difference then I'm afraid it's natural behaviour for inline elements (space between words).. there are hacks out there that involve HTML comments or removing the spacing or splitting the `img` tags, but if you can't have (or don't want) an HTML workaround - then something like this should work

**CSS:**

```
div {word-spacing: -4px; background: #eee; border: 1px solid #000; width: 600px;}
div p {word-spacing: 0;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50/dad/fff" alt="my mini thing" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50/000/fff" alt="my mini thing" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50/dad/fff" alt="my mini thing" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50/000/fff" alt="my mini thing" />
<p>the div containing these images and text has it's word-spacing set to -4px which removes the default whitespace</p>
<p>but then you want some text with normal spacing reset the word-spacing to 0 on the &lt;p&gt; elements, which is the default</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is your code:

```
#footerlinks a, #footerlinks img{
```

but `footerlinks` is **class** not an id, so use this:

```
.footerlinks a, .footerlinks img{
```

Answer (score 0):

ways to skin cats...

http://jsfiddle.net/eCSYt/45/

**Update for bazmegakapa:**

Sorry assumed the code was pretty easy to follow and I just presented it as an alternative way to approach it..

The gaps were caused by the white space in the HTML formatting - which is significant. By setting the font-size to 1px (actually 0 would be better if it is supported xbrowser) the white space is too small to render. In a real page you may also need to zero the line-height as well.

I used text-align to centre the text just to show an alternative method... and it has the advantage that you don't need to know the total width of the images

Comment: Care to post a bit more than just a simple link? At least describe the way you solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry assumed the code was pretty easy to follow and I just presented it as an alternative way to approach it.. The gaps were caused by the white space inside the HTML code, by setting the font-size:

Comment: Please edit your answer and describe your solution, links might get broken and others who will find this question later will not be able to see your answer.