# vertical alignment of div inside another - issue

Tags: css, css-float

I originally had floating divs and i wanted content inside these floats to be vertically aligned.

This was giving me troubles so i had to remove floats.

I came around this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vpA3/22/) referred in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661520/centering-2-divs-inside-another-vertically).

And used the fiddle to get desired layout. But i am facing troubles vertically aligning divs.

I tried,

```
vertical-align:middle;
display:table-cell;
```

For `parent` containers and

```
display: inline-block;
```

for `child` contents.

1) In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vpA3/156/). I want the `right` to be vertically aligned inside `right-container`.

To say in other words. I want to have `two divs` vertically aligned inside a `main div`, and divs inside each of two divs need to be vertically alined.

2) How can i achieve the vertical alignment inside the floats? So i may not change my original layout. Say in the fiddle right and left are `floats`.

Need some pointers.

**Edit:**

This might be simpler with tables. But i am looking for div based solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

Added: `<div id="right" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
        RIGHT
    </div>`

jsFiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/5vpA3/157/

Comment: This will work if you are not worried about support IE v5.5, 6, or 7.

Comment: Oh! no. I want the inner div `right` in the middle of `right-container`. so following the fiddle red needs to aligned inside green and the green should seem to be floated right of blue.

Comment: @MatthewCox, i might not be worried about Ie < 7 Support. But i would like to know the hack for them. I would check that out. :)

Comment: @tmpmember. I just edited the height and width of the main container in your fiddle. Looks like it broke. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/5vpA3/159/

Comment: @Mashit you need to change the widths of the other divs to reflect your changes: http://jsfiddle.net/RTGfU/ I used percentages but you could use pixels, if you that's the way you prefer.

Comment: thnx @akaDevo, but left(the one in blue) and right(green) are still not aligned. i just changed height of green to 80% of the main. can you please check. http://jsfiddle.net/RTGfU/1/